# Redis: deleting old unused data

Tags: redis

Does Redis have some default expire values? How does it get rid of old unused values? Does it do it at all? Or, does it just collect data until I delete it manually or until it runs out of memory? Can't find anything about it in docs and FAQ.

Comment: Haven't you see TTL in redis https://redis.io/commands/ttl

Comment: I have, but to get something from ttl I have to set expire first, don't I?

Comment: While creating keys, create with specifying `TTL`. That may help you. Or manually for all keys, set `expire`

Answer (score 3):

You can manually set time out for your keys. after the time out is reached, redis will automatically delete the key and its value.
see: https://redis.io/commands/expire